Exif rotation value after taking a picture is not being captured correctly in Flutter
I am trying to take a picture, and then trying to capture the exif rotation value of an image and based on that value, trying to rotate the image. I am using exif package. Even tho the image is rotated 90 CW, it gives a value of Horizantal (normal) which is incorrect. Is there any way to handle this in flutter? I have seen github issues but not sure what is the resolution. Can someone help?
I have tried to get the exif rotation value after image is captured. Based on that value, I am setting a rotation value like -90, 90, 180, etc. and then I am using copyRotate method and sending this rotation value as parameter. But the exif rotation value itself is incorrect.
